# Create new Excel table with additional years for people

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I have a list of people's names and their start year, how can Excel (2016) create a new table that includes every year from each person's start year up to this year?

e.g. Input Table has the data, and want to create Result Table without using macros (due to system security settings):

[image: Excel Example to add additional years]

Comment: May I know `Power Query` is applicable then it would quite be easy to achieve. Once you upload in Query Window and add a custom column with `={[Start Year]..Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow())}` and expand to new Rows. The Persons will be repeated to the number of times the years are allocated.

Comment: Yes PQ is fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> which is available from **Excel 2010+ onwards**, assuming as per post, there is no restrictions in using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> other than <kbd>VBA</kbd>. That said to do the task using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>, follow the steps:

[image]

---

- First convert the source range into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Year", each {[Start Year]..Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow())}),
    #"Expanded Year" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Year"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Year",{"Start Year"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---